# SAPUI5 only update specific binding

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In SAPUI5 I have a Model ("sModel") filled with metadata.

In this model I have a property "/aSelectedNumbers".

I also have a panel, of which I want to change the visibility depending on the content of the "/aSelectedNumbers" property.

**update**

first controller:

```
var oModelMeta = cv.model.recycleModel("oModelZAPRegistratieMeta", that);

//the cv.model.recycleModel function sets the model to the component 
//if that hasn't been done so already, and returns that model. 
//All of my views are added to a sap.m.App, which is returned in the 
//first view of this component.

var aSelectedRegistratieType = [];
var aSelectedDagdelen = ["O", "M"];
oModelMeta.setProperty("/aSelectedRegistratieType", aSelectedRegistratieType);
oModelMeta.setProperty("/aSelectedDagdelen", aSelectedDagdelen);
```

First Panel (Which has checkboxes controlling the array in question):

```
sap.ui.jsfragment("fragments.data.ZAPRegistratie.Filters.RegistratieTypeFilter", {

  createContent: function(oInitData) {

var oController = oInitData.oController;
var fnCallback = oInitData.fnCallback;
var oModel = cv.model.recycleModel("oModelZAPRegistratieMeta", oController);

var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel( {
  content: new sap.m.Label( {
    text: "Registratietype",
    width: "120px"
  })
});

function addCheckBox(sName, sId) {
  var oCheckBox = new sap.m.CheckBox( {
    text: sName,
    selected: {
      path: "oModelZAPRegistratieMeta>/aSelectedRegistratieType",
      formatter: function(oFC) {
        if (!oFC) { return false; }
        console.log(oFC);
        return oFC.indexOf(sId) !== -1;
      }
    },
    select: function(oEvent) {
      var aSelectedRegistratieType = oModel.getProperty("/aSelectedRegistratieType");
      var iIndex = aSelectedRegistratieType.indexOf(sId);

      if (oEvent.getParameters().selected) {
        if (iIndex === -1) {
          aSelectedRegistratieType.push(sId);
          oModel.setProperty("/aSelectedRegistratieType", aSelectedRegistratieType);
        }
      } else {
        if (iIndex !== -1) {
          aSelectedRegistratieType.splice(iIndex, 1);
          oModel.setProperty("/aSelectedRegistratieType", aSelectedRegistratieType);

        }
      }
      // arrays update niet live aan properties
    oModel.updateBindings(true); //******** <<===== SEE HERE
    if (fnCallback) {
      fnCallback(oController);
    }
  },
  width: "120px",
  enabled: {
    path: "oModelZAPRegistratieMeta>/bChanged",
    formatter: function(oFC) {
      return oFC !== true;
    }
  }
  });
  oPanel.addContent(oCheckBox);
}

addCheckBox("Presentielijst (dag)", "1");
addCheckBox("Presentielijst (dagdelen)", "2");
addCheckBox("Uren (dagdelen)", "3");
addCheckBox("Tijd (dagdelen)", "4");

    return oPanel;

  }
});
```

Here is the panel of which the visibility is referred to in the question. Note that it DOES work after oModel.updateBindings(true) (see comment in code above), but otherwise it does not update accordingly.

```
sap.ui.jsfragment("fragments.data.ZAPRegistratie.Filters.DagdeelFilter", {

  createContent: function(oInitData) {

    var oController = oInitData.oController;
    var fnCallback = oInitData.fnCallback;
    var oModel = cv.model.recycleModel("oModelZAPRegistratieMeta", oController);

    var oPanel = new sap.m.Panel( {
      content: new sap.m.Label( {
        text: "Dagdeel",
        width: "120px"
      }),
      visible: {
        path: "oModelZAPRegistratieMeta>/aSelectedRegistratieType",
        formatter: function(oFC) {
          console.log("visibility");
          console.log(oFC);
          if (!oFC) { return true; }
          if (oFC.length === 0) { return true; }
          return oFC.indexOf("2") !== -1;
        }
      }
    });

    console.log(oPanel);

    function addCheckBox(sName, sId) {
      var oCheckBox = new sap.m.CheckBox( {
        text: sName,
        selected: {
          path: "oModelZAPRegistratieMeta>/aSelectedDagdelen",
          formatter: function(oFC) {
            if (!oFC) { return false; }
            console.log(oFC);
            return oFC.indexOf(sId) !== -1;
          }
        },
        select: function(oEvent) {
          var aSelectedDagdelen = oModel.getProperty("/aSelectedDagdelen");
          var iIndex = aSelectedDagdelen.indexOf(sId);

          if (oEvent.getParameters().selected) {
            if (iIndex === -1) {
              aSelectedDagdelen.push(sId);
              oModel.setProperty("/aSelectedDagdelen", aSelectedDagdelen);
            }
          } else {
            if (iIndex !== -1) {
              aSelectedDagdelen.splice(iIndex, 1);
              oModel.setProperty("/aSelectedDagdelen", aSelectedDagdelen);
            }
          }
          if (fnCallback) {
            fnCallback(oController);
          }
        },
        enabled: {
          path: "oModelZAPRegistratieMeta>/bChanged",
          formatter: function(oFC) {
            return oFC !== true;
          }
        },
        width: "120px"
      });
      oPanel.addContent(oCheckBox);
    }

    addCheckBox("Ochtend", "O", true);
    addCheckBox("Middag", "M", true);
    addCheckBox("Avond", "A");
    addCheckBox("Nacht", "N");

    return oPanel;

  }
});
```

Comment: can you paste a jsbin example? When i set the property the subsequent UI is automatically hidden.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question so I started to create a small [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pocasisiwu/1/edit?js,console,output) to reproduce this issue. However, in every case (when the actual values changes) the model notifies its listeners properly. It works well for Arrays, too. You can use the JSBin to check if anything differs from your solution.

Comment: @TimGerlach in the JSBin the binding works as I would expect. However, this is a simplified version of my situation. I updated my question with all the relevant code. I should note that other bindings to the same property (such as checkboxes being enabled) work properly, and as mentioned before after forcing an update it also works properly.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I don't see any code where the fragment is connected to the model. This might be necessary explicitly.

Comment: it is connected as follows:
sap.ui.core.Component > sap.m.App (pages)  > sap.ui.jsview (content) > sap.m.Panel (content) > shown fragments

Comment: Alright. Just to make it sure. Do you retrieve the model in your fragment when using this.getModel("oModelZAPRegistratieMeta");

Comment: No, console.logging that returns undefined. However, when I just log "this", I can see that the model IS present in "oPropagatedProperties/oModels"

Comment: Ok, then try to set the model explicitly. Use either this.setModel in your fragment or set it where you instantiate the jsfragment.

Comment: I just tried, and unfortunately it doesn't work. However, I did find out that the "selected" binding of my checkboxes (which also binds a boolean property to an array) also DOES NOT work in the absence of oModel.updateBindings(true);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89252/discussion-between-tim-gerlach-and-daniel-camps).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the model doesn´t trigger a change event is that the reference to the Array does not change.

A possible way to change the value is to create a new Array everytime you read it from the model:

```
var newArray = oModel.getProperty("/aSelectedNumbers").slice();
// do your changes to the array
// ...
oModel.setProperty("/aSelectedNumbers", newArray);
```

This [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mecocomoza/edit?js,console,output) illustrates the issue.